# Access attributes in ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

I am trying to write a custom function that will throw an error if the amount of associated objects are `>=4`

I am wondering how i can access the keys/values in the contained hash and run a validation on it

if i do this

```
animal = FactoryGirl.create(:animal, images_count: 4)
a = animal.animal_images
ap(a)
```

I get this returned

```
#<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [
#<AnimalImage id: 520, animal_id: 158, image: "yp2.jpg", created_at: "2014-10-15 13:45:11", updated_at: "2014-10-15 13:45:11">, 
#<AnimalImage id: 521, animal_id: 158, image: "yp2.jpg", created_at: "2014-10-15 13:45:11", updated_at: "2014-10-15 13:45:11">, 
#<AnimalImage id: 522, animal_id: 158, image: "yp2.jpg", created_at: "2014-10-15 13:45:11", updated_at: "2014-10-15 13:45:11">, 
#<AnimalImage id: 523, animal_id: 158, image: "yp2.jpg", created_at: "2014-10-15 13:45:11", updated_at: "2014-10-15 13:45:11">
]
```

So i thought of using .map

```
animal = FactoryGirl.create(:animal, images_count: 4)
 a = animal.animal_images
 map = a.each.map { |i| i.image }
  if map.length >= 4
    ap('MORE THAN 4 IMAGES')
  end

"MORE THAN 4 IMAGES"
```

So that iterates through the CollectionProxy. However how can i get this formatted into a correct rspec test and perform the logic in a custom validation function.

I thought my test would look like this

```
it 'should display an error message when too many images are uploaded' do
 animal = FactoryGirl.create(:animal, images_count: 4)
 animal.max_num_of_images
 expect(animal.errors[:base]).to include("Max of 3 images allowed")
end
```

and just to get the pass for now (add error message) with no logic i have

```
class AnimalImage < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :animal
 validate :max_num_of_images, :if => "image?"

 def max_num_of_images
  errors.add(:base, "Max of 3 images allowed")
 end
end
```

but it seems as if the test doesnt get past the first line

```
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
Validation failed: Max of 3 images allowed
```

the above is thrown in the console

This is my factory

```
FactoryGirl.define do
 factory :animal, class: Animal do

 ignore do
   images_count 0
 end

 after(:create) do |animal, evaluator|
  create_list(:animal_image, evaluator.images_count, animal: animal)
 end
end 
end

FactoryGirl.define do
 factory :animal_image do
   image { File.open("#{Rails.root}/spec/fixtures/yp2.jpg") }
 end 
end
```

i'm probably going about this in the most backwards way possible, does anyone have any suggestions please

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to write a custom function that will throw an error if the amount of associated objects are >=4

You are overcomplicating things. *If you just want to count the number of records in a collection then you can simply do **animal.animal_images.size***. So your model will look like this:

```
class Animal < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :animal_images
  validate :max_num_of_images

  def max_num_of_images
    errors.add(:base, "Max of 3 images allowed") if self.animal_images.size >= 4
  end
end
```

Comment: thank you, so validating in the animal model rather than the animal_image model then..

Comment: @Richlewis It depends on what you are doing in app. In your code you are testing for **animal.errors[:base]** so validated it in animal model but you can do either way. Will have to update code accordingly